# Compile and run C code for Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I would like to create any run-able file from simple C code that would be able to run in the libraries level of Android.
I'm new to Android and all what I found till now is the option to use the NDK which requires java code also - and it runs the application in the applications level - and I want it to run as a system command line(Is it possible?) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the bottom up.

Going C (or C++) does not grant your code extra rights under Android.

There are different options of doing all your development without Java. There are frameworks for pure C++ (like NativeActivity), or for C# (MonoDroid), or Scala, or Ruby, or whatnot.

Android NDK also allows to simply build an executable - one that can be run from command line, and has no GUI. Your Android app can launch such executable via standard `Java Runtime.exec()` and her siblings. Or you can launch this executable from a [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dplay+store+terminal+emulator) or `adb shell`.

If you have root access on your device (or if you flash your own mod), you can launch an executable through the standard Linux `init.rc` or similar.

Note that in the latter case, you can easily grant your executable `root` or other permissions.

Comment: Is there a way to see any output information from my C code on the android side when I use adb shell?

Comment: You can find some (exotic) examples of such app writing directly to frame buffer. The easiest is to use a terminal emulator.

Comment: What is that terminal emulator? Can you please provide a link  - or more details about it? Do you mean using eclipse?

Comment: I referred to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dplay+store+terminal+emulator or any of its competitors.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to compile your code to executable, and then directly launch it from ADB shell. Basically, when you compile your code (assume you have a cpp file called `hello.cpp`) using ndk-build, write your Android.mk like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
        hello.cpp

LOCAL_MODULE:= hello
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Then you can use ADB tool to help you push the executables into your device, and run it via adb shell, for example,

```
adb shell "mkdir -p /data/test"
adb push hello /data/test/
adb shell "cd /data/test & chmod 777 hello & ./hello"
```

The above method requires you to have root permission, otherwise you cannot `chmod` or launch the native executable.

There is a tool called [**Android Native Program Launcher**](https://github.com/robertwgh/AndroidNativeLauncher), which allows you to run native code in a un-rooted device, you can give it a try.

Another way to push the executable binary to `/data/local/tmp/` folder, and you will have full control over the executable as well. 
`adb push you_binary /data/local/tmp/